# Moving an inner class to another outer class using bcel

Tags: java, inner-classes, bcel

I want to move an inner class from an outer class to another outer class. Is it possible to do it using bcel? 
For e.g:

```
class Outer1{
    ---
    class Inner{
     ----
    }
}
```

will be converted to:

```
class Outer2{
    ---
    class Inner{
        ----
    }
}
```

and

```
class Outer1{
    ----
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So why can't you just do it manually?

Comment: Actually there is a large class pool and i have to do this for each and every class. This is needed as a part of code obfuscation.

Comment: The inner-outer class relationship is just a meta information which does not affect the way the compiled code works. Usually such information is just removed by obfuscators. But it would be easy to swap the classes if you want to irritate decompilers. It’s as easy as swapping two `short` values in the class file.